# Typification of context variable at typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a few helper functions which are united into container object. And that functions can be called from any place at code.

```
const Utils = {
    isSomeMethod: function (a: INodeType, b: INodeType) {
         // Some logic
    },

    _nodeCheck: function (n: INodeType) {
        //  `this` : {
        //      node: INodeType,
        //      nn: INodeType,   
        //  }

        return (n !== this.node && Utils.isSomeMethod(n, this.nn));
    },

    ...
}
```

That function can take arguments and also context variable **`this`** I have a question is there possibility to set any specific type to **`context variable`**.

**NOTE:** In example above method `_nodeCheck` have to take context variable with type `{node: INodeType, nn: INodeType}` (that 3rd party solution and **I can't change it**) also that method widely used in my code and **I would like to have type checking**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the type of `this` as an extra parameter to the function. This parameter will not be emitted to JavaScript and will just be used for type checking.

```
const Utils = {
    isSomeMethod: function (a: INodeType, b: INodeType) {
         // Some logic
    },

    _nodeCheck: function (this: {node: INodeType, nn: INodeType}, n: INodeType) {
        // This as the type specified above and is checked.
        return (n !== this.node && Utils.isSomeMethod(n, this.nn));
    },

    ...
}
let node!: INodeType;
Utils._nodeCheck(node) // not allowed this (aka Utils) is not assignable to {node: INodeType, nn: INodeType}
```

This is covered in the documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters).

Comment: @t-j-crowder 10x for the doc reference